# Validating an email in a DB

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

The following code login the users into the platform but only with registered emails but when the email is not registered the code doesn't show the alert. Any Help!

```
function Loguear() {
            if ( document.getElementById('email_login').value != "" ) {

            var la_Arreglo = new Array();
            la_Arreglo[la_Arreglo.length] = new Objeto_Servidor ('accion' , 'Loguear' );
            la_Arreglo[la_Arreglo.length] = new Objeto_Servidor ('email'  , document.getElementById('email_login').value );

            $.post( './siev/php/Funciones_Generales.php', { 'accion':'Loguear','email':document.getElementById('email_login').value, 'clave':document.getElementById('clave_login').value },
                function(data) {
                    //alert( data);

                    var li_Errado = data.search(/error/i);

                    if ( li_Errado != -1 ) {
                        //alert('error login' );
                      _toastr("Estamos verificando su inicio de sesión - Logueo Errado","top-center","error",false);                     
                        top.location.reload();
                    } else {
                       // alert('ok login');
                      _toastr("Estamos verificando su inicio de sesión","top-center","default",false);
                        top.location.reload();
                    }
                }
            );

        } else {
            //alert('debe diligencia el email y la clave.');
           _toastr("Debe Ingresar su email para loguearse","top-center","error",false);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: The alerts have been commented out. Maybe that's why they don't show?

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Some lines were uncommented and it worked.